# Rearrange Columns of a text file in a "Custom Order" using a Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a tab delimited text file called "data.txt" which looks like

data.txt

```
col2   col3   col4   col1
val1   val5   val9   val13
val2   val6   val10  val14
val3   val7   val11  val15
val4   val8   val12  val16
...
```

and I have an array `col_order = [col1, col2, col3, col4]`

The Objective is to rearrange the columns in "data.txt" according to the order in array "col_order" **using a shell script**.

Final Output

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
val13  val1   val5   val9
val14  val2   val6   val10
val15  val3   val7   val11
val16  val4   val8   val12
```

My Progress So Far

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n"; S=OFS="\t"}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {f[$i] = i}{ print $(f["col1"]),$(f["col2"]),$(f["col3"]),$(f["col4"])}}' data.txt> data_corrected.txt
```

The above statement works as expected, but the order is hard coded in the statement, Couldn't figure out how to take the order from array and pass it in the statement.

I'm open to any other approach as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: awk is your friend here.

Comment: wrt `I have an array` - a shell array or an awk array?

Comment: @EdMorton shell array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
cat script.bash
List=( col1 col2 col3 col4 )
##echo ${List[*]}
awk -v bash_arr_val="${List[*]}" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(bash_arr_val,array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    array_with_bash_values_as_index[array[i]]=i
  }
}

FNR==1{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if($i in array_with_bash_values_as_index){
     actual_array[array_with_bash_values_as_index[$i]]=i
   }
 }
}
{
 for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
   printf("%s%s",$actual_array[i],i==NF?ORS:OFS)
 }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
val13 val1 val5 val9
val14 val2 val6 val10
val15 val3 val7 val11
val16 val4 val8 val12
```

---

EDIT by Ed Morton for variable name suggestions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    numOutFlds = split(bash_arr_val,outNr2name)
    for ( outNr=1; outNr<=numOutFlds; outNr++ ) {
        fldName = outNr2name[outNr]
        name2outNr[fldName] = outNr
    }
}

FNR==1 {
    for ( inNr=1; inNr<=NF; inNr++ ) {
        fldName = $inNr
        outNr = name2outNr[fldName]
        outNr2inNr[outNr] = inNr
    }
}
{
    for ( outNr=1; outNr<=numOutFlds; outNr++ ) {
        inNr = outNr2inNr[outNr]
        fldValue = $inNr
        printf "%s%s", fldValue, (outNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v bash_arr_val='col1 col2 col3 col4' -f tst.awk file
col1 col2 col3 col4
val13 val1 val5 val9
val14 val2 val6 val10
val15 val3 val7 val11
val16 val4 val8 val12
```

and here's how I'd really write it if I was just creating a script for myself rather than using so many temp variables, etc. to make it as clear as possible for others to understand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    numOutFlds = split(bash_arr_val,outNr2name)
    for ( outNr=1; outNr<=numOutFlds; outNr++ ) {
        name2outNr[outNr2name[outNr]] = outNr
    }
}

FNR==1 {
    for ( inNr=1; inNr<=NF; inNr++ ) {
        f[name2outNr[$inNr]] = inNr
    }
}
{
    for ( outNr=1; outNr<=numOutFlds; outNr++ ) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[outNr]), (outNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v bash_arr_val='col1 col2 col3 col4' -f tst.awk file
col1 col2 col3 col4
val13 val1 val5 val9
val14 val2 val6 val10
val15 val3 val7 val11
val16 val4 val8 val12
```

Comment: Nice attempt at meaningful array names, much better than `a`, `b,`, etc.! FWIW when coming up with names for arrays that just map from one value to another, I try to name them based on what that mapping is. For example `array[]` maps output field numbers to field names so I'd name it `outNr2name[]`, then `array_with_bash_values_as_index[]` maps field names to output field numbers so I'd name it `name2outNr[]` and `actual_array` maps output field numbers to input field numbers so it'd be `outNr2inNr[]`.

Comment: Then when you write statements like `outNr2inNr[name2outNr[$i]]=i` it's IMHO quite a bit clearer at a glance what you're doing than `actual_array[array_with_bash_values_as_index[$i]]=i`. Ditto for `printf("%s%s",$(outNr2inNr[i]),i==NF?ORS:OFS)` vs `printf("%s%s",$actual_array[i],i==NF?ORS:OFS)`, etc. (I just added the parens for clarity). If you then for the icing on the cake if you used variable names like `outNr` and `inNr` instead of `i` and set/use a temp variable `fldName` insiide the loops instead of using `$i` directly it all becomes extremely crystal clear what's going on.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes sir; I am learning on it, will try to improve more sir.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit your answer to show how I'd write the script using those names? You can remove it again or do whatever else you like with it afterwards.

Comment: @EdMorton, I will mind when you edit my answer? "that can never happen sir", please always feel free to edit sir, please do.

Comment: OK, done. Doing so uncovered a bug - your final loop needs to be on the output field numbers, not the input field numbers. As you have it written it'd fail cryptically (it'd print the whole line in place of the missing field) if there were fewer output fields to print than there are input fields.

Comment: I got rid of the test for `if($i in array_with_bash_values_as_index){` because you don't need it. If that condition is false then you end up mapping `actual_array[0] = i` but you never access the 0th element of that array anywhere so it doesn't matter. Having all the temp variables in my example is overkill for this particular case, I just laid it all out for clarity and to show how to name variables. It's also pretty common for `out2inNr[]` to just be named `f[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a final solution, but an improvement of the code of the PO, where the column order is not hard coded:

```
#!/bin/bash

col_order=$1

awk -v col_order_string="$col_order" -v OFS='\t' '
  BEGIN {
    split(col_order_string, col_order, ",");
  }
  NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      f[$i] = i
    }
  }
  {
    s = ""
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
      printf "%s%s", s, $(f[col_order[i]]);
      s = OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
  }
' data.txt
```

Invoke as

```
./script 'col1,col2,col3,col4'
```